# How to remove duplicates in a list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples:

```
   exampleList = [("a", "januari", 10), ("b", "februari", 12), ("a", "februari", 12)]

   wantedList = [("a", "januari", 10), ("b", "februari", 12)]
```

So when the first item of the tuples in the list is double or more, i want to remove the duplicates. The end result has to be the wantedList.
In a normal list i can do the "make a dictionary" trick but i dont know how to solve it with a list of tuples.

Comment: How would you do this by hand if I gave you the list of data on a piece of paper? I suggest starting by describing the steps in words. Write this down in as much detail as you can think of before trying to write code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can proceed with dict comprehension :

```
tmp_list = [("a", "januari", 10), ("b", "februari", 12), ("a", "februari", 12)]
tmp_dict = {elem[0]: elem for elem in tmp_list}

wanted_list = list(tmp_dict.values())
```

result is :

```
[('a', 'februari', 12), ('b', 'februari', 12)]
```

If you want to keep the first occurence, you can use `reversed` :

```
tmp_list = [("a", "januari", 10), ("b", "februari", 12), ("a", "februari", 12)]
tmp_dict = {elem[0]: elem for elem in reversed(tmp_list)}

wanted_list = list(tmp_dict.values())
```

Which gives you :

```
[('a', 'januari', 10), ('b', 'februari', 12)]
```

Comment: What does a dict comprehension do for duplicate keys? Does it keep the first occurrence? Or overwrite with the most recent occurrence? Or error?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I added an explanation of how to keep the first occurence

Comment: Great! I was asking because I was genuinely curious what the behavior is. Looks like it keeps the last occurrence, I guess.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes, it keep the last occurence. More precisely, each time a key/value couple is added, there are two cases :
1. key does not exist => new item in dict is created
2. key does exist => the new value replaces the old one

Comment: Tx, bit stupid of me totally overlooked that the tuple kan be a value in the dict.